# Efficient way of inflating Hashmap<Integer,List<Items>> data into the Recyclerview Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my app I want to display Hashmap data in a RecyclerView. I was able to display them successfully. But I wanna know whether there is any efficient way of doing that. For example using nested Recyclerview or any other method.

JSON

```
[
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"01. Less than 0",
      "month":3,
      "count":508
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"02. 1-5",
      "month":3,
      "count":1573
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"03. 6-10",
      "month":3,
      "count":737
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"04. 11-15",
      "month":3,
      "count":278
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"05. 16-20",
      "month":3,
      "count":129
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"06. 21-25",
      "month":3,
      "count":112
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"07. 26-30",
      "month":3,
      "count":85
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"08. 31-35",
      "month":3,
      "count":41
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"09. More than 35",
      "month":3,
      "count":165
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"01. Less than 0",
      "month":4,
      "count":300
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"02. 1-5",
      "month":4,
      "count":977
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"03. 6-10",
      "month":4,
      "count":531
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"04. 11-15",
      "month":4,
      "count":333
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"05. 16-20",
      "month":4,
      "count":144
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"06. 21-25",
      "month":4,
      "count":103
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"07. 26-30",
      "month":4,
      "count":52
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"08. 31-35",
      "month":4,
      "count":28
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"09. More than 35",
      "month":4,
      "count":76
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"01. Less than 0",
      "month":5,
      "count":281
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"02. 1-5",
      "month":5,
      "count":727
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"03. 6-10",
      "month":5,
      "count":366
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"04. 11-15",
      "month":5,
      "count":204
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"05. 16-20",
      "month":5,
      "count":72
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"06. 21-25",
      "month":5,
      "count":40
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"07. 26-30",
      "month":5,
      "count":46
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"08. 31-35",
      "month":5,
      "count":15
   },
   {
      "type":"CLAIMS PAID",
      "category":"09. More than 35",
      "month":5,
      "count":27
   }        
]

public class Items{
    private String type;
    private String category;
    private int month;
    private String count;
}
```

I am adding json request data to following Arraylist.

```
ArrayList<Items> ariList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then group those list data to a HashMap using month

```
Map<Integer, List<Items>> objectsPer = ariList.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Items::getMonth));
```

Also I have created another list which include all months in the ariList. For example it has month as {3,4,5}

```
ArrayList<Integer> monthList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I have successfully display data in my RecyclerView.

onBindViewHolder

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ArrayList<Items> dataList = (ArrayList<Items>) objectsPer.get(monthList.get(position));
    for (Items dataObject : dataList) {

        if (dataObject.getCategory().equals(("01. Less than 0"))) {
            holder.ariType1.setText("Less than 0");
            holder.ariMonth1.setText(String.valueOf(dataObject.getMonth()));
            holder.ariCount1.setText(dataObject.getCount());
        } else if (dataObject.getCategory().equals(("02. 1-5"))) {
            holder.ariType2.setText("1-5");
            holder.ariMonth2.setText(String.valueOf(dataObject.getMonth()));
            holder.ariCount2.setText(dataObject.getCount());
        } else if (dataObject.getCategory().equals(("03. 6-10"))) {
            holder.ariType3.setText("6-10");
            holder.ariMonth3.setText(String.valueOf(dataObject.getMonth()));
            holder.ariCount3.setText(dataObject.getCount());
        } else if (dataObject.getCategory().equals(("04. 11-15"))) {
            holder.ariType4.setText("11-15");
            holder.ariMonth4.setText(String.valueOf(dataObject.getMonth()));
            holder.ariCount4.setText(dataObject.getCount());
        } else if (dataObject.getCategory().equals(("05. 16-20"))) {
            holder.ariType5.setText("16-20");
            holder.ariMonth5.setText(String.valueOf(dataObject.getMonth()));
            holder.ariCount5.setText(dataObject.getCount());
        } else if (dataObject.getCategory().equals(("06. 21-25"))) {
            holder.ariType6.setText("21-25");
            holder.ariMonth6.setText(String.valueOf(dataObject.getMonth()));
            holder.ariCount6.setText(dataObject.getCount());
        } else if (dataObject.getCategory().equals(("07. 26-30"))) {
            holder.ariType7.setText("26-30");
            holder.ariMonth7.setText(String.valueOf(dataObject.getMonth()));
            holder.ariCount7.setText(dataObject.getCount());
        } else if (dataObject.getCategory().equals(("08. 31-35"))) {
            holder.ariType8.setText("31-35");
            holder.ariMonth8.setText(String.valueOf(dataObject.getMonth()));
            holder.ariCount8.setText(dataObject.getCount());
        } else if (dataObject.getCategory().equals(("09. More than 35"))) {
            holder.ariType9.setText("More than 35");
            holder.ariMonth9.setText(String.valueOf(dataObject.getMonth()));
            holder.ariCount9.setText(dataObject.getCount());
        } else {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't actually need a map for this, You could create a class lets say `MonthsItem`, and have 2 members as `int type` for months and Arraylist to have all the items for that month. and then use `ArryaList<MonthsItem>` to get all the data required for recycler view

Comment: thanks for the reply. Then how may I group same month data?

Comment: You need to check for the `type` in the ArrayList of `MonthsItem` this will be O(n) * 12 which is o(n*n) a bad way to approach it. You can try `ArrayList<Items> [] months = new ArrayList[12]` here size of months array is 12 cuz 0= Jan, 1 = Feb and soo on 11 = Dec. And Then fill the months Array with same month data. this will be O(n) to get the Month.